# Create my own caching proxy from scratch

Tags: java, proxy

I'm interested in creating my own caching proxy, either in Java or Go. I suspect I need a few docs that state specification but I don't know where to find them or what else would be needed.

Checking github projects, they are either very old or I don't understand what spec they are coding to. Any help?

Comment: Proxy for what protocol?

Comment: Ah yes. The HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this article.

https://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/07/11/what_proxies_must_do

See the `Cache Correctly` section.

It has links to the following specifications.

1. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-14#section-2.2
2. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-14#section-3.2

Also check this one http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/08/20/caching-http-post-requests-and-responses/

This also refers to the following specifications.

1. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.9
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13.1.1

I don't think there's more than this to the caching in the specification that you have to respect the HTTP headers. Cache implementation itself is probably choice of developer.